# Silverlight Style Setter can't see property

Tags: silverlight, styles

I'm trying to apply a style to a MapPolyline from the bing maps silverlight classes.

I have this style defined:

```
<Style x:Key="routeStyle" TargetType="map:MapPolyline">
    <Setter Property="Stroke">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Magenta" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10" />
</Style>
```

And I get this error when it runs:

> The property 'Stroke' was not found in type 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.MapPolyline'.

Which is in contradiction to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.mappolyline_members.aspx

I wondered if maybe it was struggling to find the property because it's declared in the base class. So I tried this:

```
<Style x:Key="routeStyle" TargetType="mapCore:MapShapeBase">
    <Setter Property="Stroke">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Magenta" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10" />
</Style>
```

But still got:

> The property 'Stroke' was not found in type 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Core.MapShapeBase'.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: From that link I don't see any DependencyProperty exposed for Stroke or StrokeThickness on MapPolyline or MapShapeBase. Are you sure this is a dependency property?

Comment: The control seems to be using the Shape class' DP so I suspect that is the problem. You might be able to do something like Property="Shape.StrokeProperty".

Comment: Ahh hah.

I was looking at this bit of documentation and it doesn't mention anything about being opnly for DPs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.setters(v=vs.95).aspx

Of course when you get down to the specific documentation it then mentions that it has to be a DP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.property(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I've just tried Property="shapes:Shape.StrokeProperty" and I get Property 'StrokeProperty' was not found in type 'MapPolyline'. So it would seem that wont work either.

Comment: AndrewS: care to add this as an answer so I can mark it as such? Since you were the one who worked through this with me and even gave a suggestion.

Comment: Added along with a basic workaround. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stroke and StrokeThickness are not backed by DependencyProperties defined for that class. Internally they are using the Stroke(Thickness)Property fields of the Shape class. One option would be to define your own attached DependencyProperty for each and within the PropertyChangeCallback you could use the associated Shape class's DP to set the value on the object. This would have the downside of being a local value (rather than a style value) but it should work for basic scenarios. e.g.

```
public static class ShapeExtensions
{
    #region Stroke
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Stroke", typeof(Brush), typeof(ShapeExtensions),
            new PropertyMetadata((Brush)null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStrokeChanged)));

    public static Brush GetStroke(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (Brush)d.GetValue(StrokeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetStroke(DependencyObject d, Brush value)
    {
        d.SetValue(StrokeProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnStrokeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.SetValue(Shape.StrokeProperty, e.NewValue);
    }
    #endregion // Stroke
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the work around I have been trying to post as the answer I came up with. Unfortunatly stack overflow won't let me self answer for another 6 hours ... but luckily you have provided it for all to see anyway :) Many thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

`Stroke` and `StrokeThickness` are not dependency properties and thus would not be available inside Style or Template. These 2 properties are uniformly non-dp throughout WPF.

As a workaround, you can create your own derived class such as `MapPolyLineEx` from `MapPolyLine` class, you can create the `new` implementations (using hiding the base class member feature of C#) of `Stroke` and `StrokeThickness` as dependency properties